# Office 2010 Deployment With MAK key via startup/shutdown script

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Office 2010 silent activation after unattended installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/148938/office-2010-silent-activation-after-unattended-installation)

We are looking at deploying Office 2010 over machine startup/shutdown scripts. I have created a msp file and configured config.xml with all the relevant options, and the install from a batch file works fine.

The issue I have is I want to install on a shutdown script, so the users turn their machine of at night and in the morning when they come in office is upgraded.

I have got the it running via a gpo shutdown script, but the issue I have is its not activating the install (we only have a MAK key so i cant setup a KMS server). I asume its because as the install is happening in the shutdown script it cant get out over the web.

The first time the user starts office its running through the process fine and activating the install, but I really dont want the users to have to do this.

Anyone any ideas?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Setup will not activate a MAK key automatically. You can call the activation script yourself however, as detailed in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this sometime ago, use this command in the last step to activate office 2010.

```
cscript.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OSPP.VBS" /act
```

Comment: Have you added this into you msp custom file or just as another shutdown script to run after the installer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Office Customization Tool (that is included with Volume License media).  When you preload the MAK key, you can set the option to auto-activate (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx#Licensing_and_user_interface for instructions on setting auto-activate).  When Office starts for the first time, it will attempt to activate with Microsoft (or via [VAMT](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11936), which I highly recommend for visibility of license use).

The advantage to doing it this way is that it doesn't require any manual intervention on your part and you can still run the installation at shut down.

Comment: I have already put this in, it works activating it if i am logged on, its just when i run as shutdown script its stuggling